# icmp.ListenPacket("udp4", "127.0.0.1") return permission denied

Tags: linux, go, icmp

In https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/icmp#ListenPacket documentation, it mentions:

> For non-privileged datagram-oriented ICMP endpoints, network must be
>   "udp4" or "udp6". The endpoint allows to read, write a few limited
>   ICMP messages such as echo request and echo reply. Currently only
>   Darwin and Linux support this.
>
> For privileged raw ICMP endpoints, network must be "ip4" or "ip6"
>   followed by a colon and an ICMP protocol number or name.

But when I try this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/net/icmp"
)

func main() {
    _, err := icmp.ListenPacket("udp4", "127.0.0.1")
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Error returned:

```golang
socket: permission denied
```

Is there something wrong in my code?

**Operating System**: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Please post a [mre] showing how you're getting that error. Also, what are you intending to ping using localhost? You would normally bind to `0.0.0.0` or another external IP.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41425527/5821408
This might help you!

Comment: @JimB added, @Subham `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ping_group_range="0   2147483647"` do the job, but how about another user ?